# How to save a spark DataFrame back into a Google BigQuery project using pyspark?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, pyspark, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataproc

I am loading a dataset from BigQuery and after some transformations, I'd like to save the transformed DataFrame back into BigQuery. Is there a way of doing this?

This is how I am loading the data:

```
df = spark.read \
  .format('bigquery') \
  .option('table', 'publicdata.samples.shakespeare') \
  .load()
```

Some transformations:

```
 df_new = df.select("word")
```

And this I how I am trying to save the data as a new table into my project area:

```
df_new \
.write \
.mode('overwrite') \
.format('bigquery') \
.save('my_project.some_schema.df_new_table')
```

Is this even possible? Is there a way to save to BQ directly?

ps: I know this works but this is not exactly what I am looking for:

```
df_new \
.write \
.mode('overwrite') \
.format('csv') \
.save('gs://my_bucket/df_new.csv')
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does this solve your problem? https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/bigquery-connector-spark-example

Comment: Resources to consider... Write a DataFrame to BigQuery table using [pandas_gbq](https://pandas-gbq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) module ->
https://pandas-gbq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/writing.html# By shelling out to the bq command-line (see PySpark example)
Use the BigQuery connector with Spark
https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/bigquery-connector-spark-example Google BigQuery support for Spark, SQL, and DataFrames (contributed by Spotify)
https://github.com/spotify/spark-bigquery

Comment: found a resource which might help  https://github.com/spotify/spark-bigquery

Answer (score 5):

Here is the documentation for the [BigQuery connector with Spark](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/bigquery-connector-spark-example)

This is how it's recommended:

```
# Saving the data to BigQuery
word_count.write.format('bigquery') \
  .option('table', 'wordcount_dataset.wordcount_output') \
  .save()
```

You set the table in the option() instead of the "save()"

Comment: It seems they have added this recently! Thanks!

Comment: Specifying the table as an option is deprecated. Instead, the `path` param of `save` should be used as stated in the question actually, but the difference is the `project` should not be specified in the table path but rather either from the service account used or explicitly using the `parentProject` option.
https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector#properties

Answer (score 0):

Following syntax will create/overite table

```
         df.write.format('bigquery').option('table', ( 'project.db.tablename')).mode("overwrite").save()
```

For more information you can refer the following link
https://dbmstutorials.com/pyspark/spark-dataframe-write-modes.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).